# I am getting result while debug the code but I see error when I run the code in python using eclipse IDE

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm facing error when I run the code. If I debug the code I could not see any error it is showing the result fine.

I don't know the exact problem. I see the below error when I run the code. But the error is not coming when I debug

```
from _elementtree import *
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'deepcopy'
```

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your code?  The module you are using probably isn’t installed properly, or you are referencing something in your code that you haven’t imported.

Answer (score 0):

I had package copy and copy module and I was using ElementTree. So element tree looking for copy module so I faced this issue. After renamed those package and module the problem fixed